# Xamarin Open Content Page In Project Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to open Xamarin forms page from Xamarin Android project.
I have a popup page. I want to call from project Android open popup page in current content page but not using new NavigationPage.

```
await Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new MyPopUpPage()));
```

Comment: You don't have to use a `NavigationPage` when using `PushModalAsync`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code instead

```
await Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new MyPopUpPage());
```

The popup method is also simple

```
await Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopPopupAsync();
```

Refer to

https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Navigation#xamarinformsinavigation-navigationextension